# Identifying SMD diode

Tags: diodes, surface-mount

I have a faulty diode (DZ1) in this circuit which I was unable to identify. I've tried a few dozen diodes already but they didn't work.

I'll share some information about the circuit:

It is used to operate an electric hair heater. The circuit is connected to the wall directly (220V AC.) This diode seem to have a huge input. Either around 200 DC or 600 AC couldn't confirm that. I think the diode is being used as some sort of voltage regulator/rectifier, but the area after the diode is expecting a 6V input and in fact removing the diode and supplying just 6V makes the circuit work as expected.

Diodes I've tried so far

> 1N4148 - 1N4001 - 1N4007 - 1N4148 - 1N5822 - FR107 - 1N5819 - 1N5399 -
> FR207 - 1N5408

I know that some of these options are ridiculous but I had them laying around so, why not.

Almost with all these I get an output voltage of 1.5/2 volts a few got me 5.8V and very little current flowing through. My circuit needs around 35 mA. Just guessing from measurements while connected to a DC battery.

[circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTDbR.jpg)

[image]

Comment: why would the diode be labeled D21 when there are only a few diodes? ... you may have misread the label ... compare label to D2

Comment: At a glance it looks like it uses a capacitive dropper style power supply. My guess it is a zener diode - voltage unknown. You could get hints from the voltage rating of the electrolytic cap and the ic. Could be 5V,12V ???

Comment: @jsotola interesting observation . I assume now it makes sense to call DZ1

Comment: @Kartman would you recommend any of these to test ? 

ST Zener Diodes ZMM5V1 5.1V 500mW <100nA @ 1V LL-34;
SMD Zener Diodes 5.1V 200mW 1uA @ 2V SOD-323;
Zener Diodes SMD 3.3V <2uA @ 1V 500mW LL-34;
Diodes Zener 12V 100nA 9.1V 500mW LL-34;

Comment: I can’t recommend as I have little information to work with. However, a 400/500mW zener would be a good start. You need to consider what caused the original zener to die. It got hot by the looks, so there was too many volts coming in.

Comment: @Kartman Originally it wasn't like that , this image was taken after i desoldered/soldered it many times for testing . 

Originally the circuit looked perfect with no burns at all . what lead me to suspect this diode that it was the only component i could find that is  shorted . 

Didn't really consider what might have caused the damage , i think it might be age and heat ? 
This heater been operational for 5 yrs . Also it didn't happen over night the heater was glitching a lot in the last few weeks . 
If you have a recommendation of think i should be checking please let me know .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working finally with

**ST Zener Diodes ZMM5V1 5.1V 500mW**

Hints from Kartman and Tim Williams helped . thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try tracing the circuit (follow traces and vias between components; remove components and check continuity if necessary).  I would guess the circled diode is a zener, in MELF package.  The left-hand circuitry looks to be EMI filtering and protection, and a capacitive dropper circuit, into a rectifier and a shunt regulator -- for which a zener is ideal.  Also, that appears to be "DZ1" not "D21" (as jsotola noted).

This is a mains-powered circuit; be very careful when probing it, using an isolation transformer if possible.